# Как сделать декоративный вывод текста в определенную форму при помощи CSS?

Tags: css3, html, css

то есть примерно так

[image]

или все-таки придется использовать JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно [примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6kx/) настраивать

```css
#one {} 
#two {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#three {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
#four {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#five {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">Один два три четыре пять</div>
<div id="two">Один два три четыре</div>
<div id="three">Один два три</div>
<div id="four">Один два</div>
<div id="five">Один</div>
```

Comment: Но если текст в блоки забивается автоматически, то лучше делать яваскриптом.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше так http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6kx/1/